# Representation of complex number with exponents with siunitx (workaround)?

Tags: siunitx

It looks like `siunitx` (by @Joseph Wright) has a limitation regarding complex numbers with exponents:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{1 + 2 i}\\ %ok, complex number
\num{2e6}\\ %ok, number with exponent
\num{1 + 2e6 i}\\ %not ok, ! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-exponent"
\end{document}
```

**Is there a workaround for this?**

The only way I found is

```
\num[parse-numbers=false]{1 + (\num[parse-numbers=true]{2e6}) i}
```

which defeats the purpose.

(I am using `siunitx` version 2.5c.)

Note that `siunitx` can handle exponents in complex number, but in the case that the exponent is the same for both parts, for example `\num{1+2i e10}`, which is a different case.

Comment: I would have written that number as `\num{1 + 2ie6}` but that gives, surprisingly to me, `(1 + 2i) × 10⁶`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, yes, and even `\num{1 + i2e6}` gives `(1+2i)×10^6`, that is fine, that is why I moved the `i` to the end, in the hope that it won't be ambiguous (for the `siunitx` parser)

Comment: This is a pretty-much deliberate limitation. Parsing complex numbers is hard enough, and it's there to support places in science where you do get for example complex frequencies. I'd need to see an example where a number with real and complex parts with an exponent only for one part comes up in the 'real world' of the scientific literature before addressing this.

Comment: @JosephWright, good that you mention it. It is true, this is not a "literature" situation, however I am just processing output and displaying with a LaTeX output for reporting purposes. Your package came as a blessing because I don't have to worry in converting the `C` output (e.g. `1.2344234234e-23` to something readable `$1.23\times 10^{-23}$`), I just let `num` process the string and even truncate (e.g. uniformly across the document) that for me. For complex numbers I have to do a little more work to separate the `real` and `imag` part, and that is where I hit the problem.

Comment: @alfC I'm more than happy to consider a feature request. The tricky part is dealing with things like `1e2 + 3e4i`: logically allowable if you permit separate exponents, but much harder for me to process :-) Also, you have to then worry about the interpretation of `1+2ie3`: is the exponent only for the second part or the whole number?

Comment: @JosephWright, well, please, and thanks for your amazing work. I wouldn't know what is the scope of the `num` parsing to say if this is a legitimate feature to request. It obviously can't process every single mathematical notation that one can come up with (and all the combinations, e.g. `2e-16 + -3i + 1/3` ). But... one possible (useful) scope is to be able to process the numeric output of popular programming languages (e.g. `C`, `C++`'s `std::complex<double>`, `FORTRAN`, `Mathematica`). And yes, I imagine that programming the parser in TeX must be a nightmare. So, thank you again.

Comment: @JosephWright, `1+2ie3` is already interpreted as `(1 + 2i) × 10⁶` and I think that is the expected result. `1+i2e3` is ambiguous, but `1+2e3i` is not in my opinion. I hope that helps for the implementation :). With respect to `C++` complex numbers it may work to say `num[language=C++]{(1.,2.)}` or (a daring) `num{(1.,2.)}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number parser in `siunitx` is intended to support the primary purpose of the package: typesetting physical quantities (numbers with units). These rarely have a complex part, and when they do (such as in some parts of electronics) the magnitude of the real and complex parts is normally similar. Thus the package understands

```
1 + 2i e3
```

as

```
$(1 + 2\mathrm{i}) \times 10^{3}$
```

as this is by far the most common requirement.

In principal the parser can be extended to cope with a wider range of inputs, but this also requires changes in how the output is generated. There is then a balance both in terms of complexity of code and of performance, as the 'common case' does not need any of this.

Feature requests are always welcome: please feel free to log one in the [tracker](https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issues/), along with links to whatever input syntax(es) would be useful!

Comment: Thank you very much, I opened a feature request, regarding more general numeric types from computer languages: https://bitbucket.org/josephwright/siunitx/issue/208/feature-request-typeset-numeric-types-from (sorry it went Anonymous)

Comment: I'll accept this answer as an statement of the current limitation and scope of the package.

Comment: @alfC Fine with me! There is an open feature request for a choice of number parsers: probably on the cards for v3 of the package, some time next year.

Comment: Hi @JosephWright, is there any update on this issue? I'd really love to be able to typeset directly things like `\SI{-3.29e-02-1.51e-04j}{\volt}`, but I understand that probably we're not too many wishing to do this ;-) Meanwhile I use the following workaround: `$(\num{-3.29e-02}\num{-1.51j e-04})\SI{}{\volt}$`.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano do you know that you can write `\si{\volt}` instead of `\SI` with a first empty argument? Oh, I see: you let `\SI` take care of the space between number and unit?

Comment: @ojdo: yes, exactly that. But at the end I changed the way results were presented: actually, the limitation on the package let me think that probably there was a better way to present them to the reader :-)